# Clojure java.lang.RuntimeException when using http://www.tryclj.com/

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure on [tryclj](http://www.tryclj.com/). Why is this not working? It should work based on [this](http://clojure.org/java_interop).

```
> (Character/toLowerCase \F)
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: toLowerCase in this context

```
> (.toLowerCase "FRED")
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: toLowerCase in this context

**Update**

The problem was the browser. I was using chrome originally. I tried it in IE and firefox and java.lang.RuntimeException: does not appear. I didn't realise the browser would make a difference.

[image]

Comment: the first line is really not working.  that should be `(Character/toLowerCase \F)`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @cfrick. I tried that in the REPL and I got the same error.

Comment: well there is something else odd, yet the first line would not work in any case, regardless, that the same (wrong) error message is shown. the second line of code works fine for me (Fx 35ish)

Comment: I just tried it in internet explorer it works. (the second one works). I was using chrome originally. I didn't realise the browser made a difference.

Comment: @dwalsh84 The browser doesn't make a difference, I'm using Chrome and both expressions evaluate correctly.

Comment: I was using and old version of chrome but then I updated it and it is still producing runtimeException. I added screenshot. @juan.facorro

Comment: @dwalsh84 This is weird, I'm getting the same exception now :(. There's something wrong with TryClj though because even `(.toString 1)` throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: toString in this context`.

Comment: @juan.facorro thank god I am not crazy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment the argument from the first expression should be a `Character` literal since the function [`Character/toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char)) expects a `char`.

The other expression should work just fine in TryClj, at least it does for me, please see the following screenshot.

[image]